# Running Spigot BuildTools.jar from PowerShell using Git Bash

Tags: java, powershell, git-bash, start-process

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script to update Spigot using Git Bash. Hopefully from the two failed PS examples below you get the gist of what I'm trying to do.

I can successfully open a Git Bash shell in the target folder and run `java -jar BuildTools.jar`. When I try to run through PowerShell, a CMD window opens and immediately closes. No errors are displayed and best I can tell, the CMD window contains no text. I prefer to use PowerShell over a CMD script because I am leveraging `Invoke-WebRequest` earlier on to get the latest version of `BuildTools.jar`. I would like to keep all this together in one script.

Example 1:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" -ArgumentList "--login -i -c ""java -jar BuildTools.jar"""
```

Example 2:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" -ArgumentList '--login', '-i', '-c', '"java -jar BuildTools.jar"'
```

Comment: Why an interactive login shell? `& bash.exe -c "java -jar BuildTools.jar"` should suffice if `bash.exe` is in your `$env:PATH`. Otherwise use the full path to the executable.

Comment: Thanks! You helped me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out thanks to an idea from [Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers).

Solution is as follows:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" -ArgumentList '-c', '"cd /c/Bitnami/Updater && java -jar BuildTools.jar"'
```